# custom dialog box in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a input textbox in a component html file.The value in that textbox will either be the text i am typing in that textbox or it has to come from a custom dialog box using md-dialog.I am able to get the value from the dialog box and show it in the textbox when i am clicking on confirm link from the dialog.

The issue is after showing the value in the textbox from the dialog box ,when i am again opening the dialog box and just clicking cancel it closes the dialog but the value in the texbox disappears .I don't want that .I want to persist the value in the textbox if i am just opening the dialog box again and closing it a without doing anything after the value is shown in the textbox.

How to achieve that?

My callingmodal component code:

cardDetails.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject ,Input,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import {SearchService} from '../sharedService/search.service';
import {ModalComponent} from './modal/modal.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FormControl ,NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import{BankdetailsService} from './modal/bankdetails.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardDetails',
  host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
    },
  templateUrl: './cardDetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardDetails.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchService]
})
export class CardDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
   public query = '';
public filteredList = [];
    public elementRef;
    public banknames = ["ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED","ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK","AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK","AIRTEL PAYMENTS BANK LIMITED","AKOLA JANATA COMMERCIAL COOPERATIVE BANK","ALLAHABAD BANK","ALMORA URBAN COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED","BANK","OTHER BANK","APNA SAHAKARI BANK LIMITED","AUSTRALIA AND NEW ZEALAND BANKING GROUP LIMITED","AXIS BANK","B N P PARIBAS","BANDHAN BANK LIMITED","BANK INTERNASIONAL INDONESIA","BANK OF AMERICA","BANK OF BAHARAIN AND KUWAIT BSC","BANK OF BARODA","BANK OF CEYLON","BANK OF INDIA","BANK OF MAHARASHTRA","BANK OF TOKYO MITSUBISHI LIMITED","BARCLAYS BANK","BASSEIN CATHOLIC COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED","BHARAT COOPERATIVE BANK MUMBAI LIMITED","CANARA BANK","CAPITAL SMALL FINANCE BANK LIMITED","CATHOLIC SYRIAN BANK LIMITED","CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA","CHINATRUST COMMERCIAL BANK LIMITED","CITI BANK","CITIZEN CREDIT COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED","CITY UNION BANK LIMITED","COMMONWEALTH BANK OF AUSTRALIA","CORPORATION BANK","CREDIT AGRICOLE CORPORATE AND INVESTMENT BANK CALYON BANK","CREDIT SUISEE AG","DCB BANK LIMITED","DENA BANK","DEOGIRI NAGARI SAHAKARI BANK LTD. AURANGABAD","DEPOSIT INSURANCE AND CREDIT GUARANTEE CORPORATION","DEUSTCHE BANK"]

submitted = false;
onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
bankdata: any[];
 ifsc : any;


queryField: FormControl = new FormControl();
searchTerm = new Subject<string>();
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService,public bankdetailservice : BankdetailsService, public dialog: MdDialog,myElement: ElementRef) { 

//this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm)
      //.subscribe(results => {
        //this.results = results.results;
      //});
 this.elementRef = myElement;
}



  ngOnInit() {

  this.queryField.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((queryField) =>  this.searchService.search(queryField))
  .subscribe(data => { if (data.status === 400) { return; }
        else { 
        this.bankdata = data.data;
        console.log(typeof(this.bankdata));

                    }
        }
      );


}

filter() {
    if (this.query !== ""){
        this.filteredList = this.banknames.filter(function(el){
            return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }.bind(this));

    }else{
        this.filteredList = [];
    }
}

select(item){
    this.query = item;
    this.filteredList = [];
}
handleClick(event){
   var clickedComponent = event.target;
   var inside = false;
   do {
       if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
           inside = true;
       }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
   } while (clickedComponent);
    if(!inside){
        this.filteredList = [];
    }
}

//selectvalue(bnkname){


//}
openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {  ifsc: this.ifsc }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.ifsc = result ;
    });
  }






}
```

carddetails component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
<h3 style="font-family: Lucida Console serif;color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);font-size: 17px;text-align: left;">Enter Payment Details</h3>
<p id ="plain">We require your bank details to transfer the <br>claim amount to you.<br>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #carddetailform = "ngForm" id="ngForm">


  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name ="name"  placeholder="Full Name" required><br><br></div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ifsc" name ="ifsc"  [(ngModel)] = ifsctext  [value]="ifsc || '' " placeholder="IFSC Code" required></div>
  <p id ="message">Don't know your IFSC Code? That's okay, <a (click)="openDialog()">Find out here!</a><br><br>





<!--<input  type = "search" id="bank" (keyup)="searchTerm.next($event.target.value)" placeholder="BANK">
<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">

      {{ result.name }}

  </li>
</ul>-->

<!-- <section class="filter-wrapper"> -->
 <!--<div class="keyword-wrapper">-->
 <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="keyword" class="form-control" name ="bankname" [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)="filter()" placeholder="BANK"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>

</div>

  <!--</div>-->


<div class="filter-select" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
  <ul  *ngFor="let item of filteredList" class="filter-select-list"><li class="artist-name">

    <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>

<!-- <button type="submit"   [disabled]="!carddetailform.form.valid" form="ngForm" id ="button"class="form-control" routerLink="/endOfSurvey" >Send Bank Details</button> -->
<button type="submit" id ="button" class="form-control" routerLink="/endOfSurvey" >Send Bank Details</button>
  </form>
</div></div></div>
```

modal component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Inject,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { Select2OptionData } from 'ng2-select2';
import {BankdetailsService} from './bankdetails.service';

//import { ModalService } from './modal/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
 banks = {};
 branch : any;
 city : any;
 ifsc : any;
 ifsctext;

 constructor(
    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public bankdetailsservice : BankdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.bankdetailsservice.getBankInfo().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.banks = data.data;

        console.log(this.banks);
        },
          (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
          () => console.log('completed')
        );

       }

       firstDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.banks["BANK"];
    console.log(val, obj);

    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj == "YES BANK") {
      this.city = this.banks["CITY"];

      console.log(this.city);
    }

  }
   secondDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.banks["CITY"];
    console.log(val, obj);

    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj == "SURAT") {
      this.branch = this.banks["BRANCH"];

      console.log(this.branch);
    }
    if(this.branch)
    this.ifsc = this.banks["IFSC"];

    console.log(this.ifsc);
  }



 onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

modal component.html

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div md-dialog-content>
    <h3>Find your IFSC Code</h3>

<div class="form-group">

  <label for="sel1"></label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sel1" (change)="firstDropDownChanged($event.target.selectedIndex -1)">
 <option data-hidden="true" value="">Bank Name</option>
 <option>
{{this.banks.BANK}}

 </option>


  </select>
  <label for="sel2"></label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sel2" (change)="secondDropDownChanged($event.target.selectedIndex -1)">
    <option data-hidden="true" value="">City</option>
    <option>
{{this.city}}

 </option>

  </select>
  <label for="sel3"></label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sel3">
    <option data-hidden="true" value="">Branch</option>
    <option>
        {{this.branch}}

    </option>
  </select>

</div>

<div md-dialog-actions>
<button md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
  <button md-button  [md-dialog-close]="this.ifsc " tabindex="2">Confirm</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

bankdetailservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class BankdetailsService {
ifsctext ;
baseUrl: string = 'https://api.techm.co.in/api/getbank/YES%20BANK/ASSOCIATE%20COOP%20BANK%20UMARWADA';
  constructor(private http: Http) { 

    }

getBankInfo() {
    return this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }



}
```

my app module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
//import { ResponsiveState, ResponsiveConfig, ResponsiveConfigInterface } from 'responsive-directives-angular2'; 
//import {ResponsiveModule, ResponsiveConfig, ResponsiveConfigInterface} from 'ng2-responsive';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MdFormFieldModule,MdInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MdDialogModule} from '@angular/material';
//import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Select2Module } from 'ng2-select2';
//import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-modal-dialog/modal.module';


import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';
import { FirstserviceService } from './webServicesCall.service/firstservice.service';
import { Ng2DeviceDetectorModule, Ng2DeviceService } from 'ng2-device-detector';
import { CameraclickService } from './cameraclick.service';
import {BankdetailsService} from './cardDetails/modal/bankdetails.service';


import {RouterModule,Router,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DefaultComponent } from './default/default.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {endOfSurveyComponent} from './endOfSurvey/endOfSurvey.component';
import {ProofOfRepairComponent} from './proofOfRepair/por.component';
import {SearchService} from './cardDetails/search.service';

//import { ClaimComponent } from './claim/claim.component';
//import { SurveyComponent } from './survey/survey.component';


import { CaptureclicksComponent } from './captureclicks/captureclicks.component';
import { CardDetailsComponent } from './cardDetails/cardDetails.component';
import { KeysPipe } from './second/keys.pipe';
import { ModalComponent } from './cardDetails/modal/modal.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent},
  { path: 'captureclicks', component: CaptureclicksComponent},
  { path: 'proofOfRepair', component: ProofOfRepairComponent},
  {path: 'endOfSurvey', component: endOfSurveyComponent},
  {path: 'cardDetails', component: CardDetailsComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SecondComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
   endOfSurveyComponent,
   CaptureclicksComponent,
   ProofOfRepairComponent,
   CardDetailsComponent,
   KeysPipe,
   ModalComponent

  ],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Select2Module,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdFormFieldModule,
    MdInputModule ,

    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers:[FirstserviceService ,CameraclickService,BankdetailsService,SearchService,Ng2DeviceService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have 3 dropdown in modal html .After selecting values from the three dropdown which are bank details it will give a ifsc code and that code i am showing it in carddetails component html where i am having a textbox with ifsc code .

I was not able to use Stackblitz because of some dependencies.Please look into this and help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the calling class, do you check whether the return value from the dialog is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your value in variable and initialize this value every time you open dialog. If you have other component you can use service to comunicate between components.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Edit:

It works

```
openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {  ifsc: this.ifsc }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      if(result != '' && result != null ) {
      this.ifsc = result ;
      }
    });
```

This if check and change only if it is not undefined or empty string

Comment: i need to define a variable with @Input in the modal component.ts file and initialize its value with the value i want to pass it to the calling modal component,and in the callingmodal component.ts i have to reuse that value from the Input variable to a variable in this class and initialize it in open dialog function. Is that approach correct? I have one more doubt . For passing data using Input decorater I have to add modal selector at the end of the callingmodal component .html ?beacuse if i do that the modal content already comes up on the calling modal page.

Comment: Edit your post and paste code of that component or better use https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: i will do that now

Comment: Hi I have used stackblitz and here is my Url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyrmve?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts. Click on Find out here and select the bank name,city and branch and click confirm .It will show the value in ifsc text box.Again click on Find out here and click either confirm or cancel without making any change in the dropdown .The ifsc value from the textbox disappears because i have added in the html its value as value || '  ' otherwise it was showing undefined

Comment: Check my solution, code is in my answer. I just added simple if in openDialog function. I hope it would work for you.

Comment: Did you check solution?

Comment: It worked .Thanks a lot. Sorry for not replying before

Answer (score 0):

**=> import modules**

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

**=> Material design dialogs**

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="animal">
    You chose: <i>{{animal}}</i>
  </li>
</ol>
```

=>**TS File**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```